# Throttle or debounce async calls in Vue 2 while passing arguments to debounced function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, throttling

I have a Vue 2 application that uses an array of objects to back a search/multiselect widget provided by [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/).

I have looked at the Vue 1 -> 2 migration guide on [debouncing calls](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed), but the example they give did not propagate the arguments from the DOM elements to the business logic.

Right now the select fires change events with every keystroke, but I would like to throttle this (EG with lodash#throttle) so I'm not hitting my API every few milliseconds while they're typing.

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
import { throttle } from 'lodash';

import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedWork: {},
      works: [],
      isLoading: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['worksList']),
  },
  methods: {
    getWorksAsync: throttle((term) => {
      // the plan is to replace this with an API call
      this.works = this.worksList.filter(work => titleMatches(work, term));
    }, 200)
  }
}
```

Problem: when the user types in the select box, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

which is happening because `this.worksList` is `undefined` inside the `throttle` function.

Curiously, when I use the dev tools debugger, `this.worksList` has the value I need to dereference, with `this` referring to the Vue component.

Currently I am not calling the API from within the component, but the problem remains the same:

1. How can I throttle this call, and have the proper `this` context to update my `this.works` list? EDIT: this is explained in [Vue Watch doesnt Get triggered when using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945943)
2. I also need to capture the user's query string from the multiselect widget to pass to the API call.

What is the proper pattern in Vue 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue Watch doesnt Get triggered when using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945943/vue-watch-doesnt-get-triggered-when-using-axios)

Comment: @zero298 I think the issue of scope (arrow fn vs `function`) is the same as in the issue you referenced.  However, the issue of getting the query string value from the UI when it's not bound to the model was an additional wrinkle.  Maybe they should be two separate issues, but it seemed like this was potentially a situation others might find themselves in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find an answer on SO (or anywhere) for this, but I eventually cobbled it together through trial and error, and from related materials here and in the docs.

**Things that work that I didn't do, and why**

It is possible to get get the value directly using a JavaScript DOM query, and it is also possible to dig in to the multiselect component's structure and get the value.  The first solution circumvents the framework, the second depends on undocumented attributes of the multiselect component.  I am avoiding both of those solutions as non-idiomatic and brittle.

**My current solution**

1. Updated an attribute on the component whenever there was a change event in the search box.  This allowed me to capture the user's query string.
2. Called my throttled async function from inside the event listener.
3. Passed a regular `function` instead of an arrow function to `throttle`, which gave the correct `this` (the Vue component.)

If anyone has a suggestion for a better way to do this in Vue 2, I'm all ears.

Here's what my solution looked like in the end:

```
<template>    
  <div>
    <label
      class="typo__label"
      for="ajax">Async select</label>
    <multiselect
      id="ajax"
      v-model="selectedWork"
      label="title"
      track-by="id"
      placeholder="Type to search"
      :options="works"
      :searchable="true"
      :loading="isLoading"
      :internal-search="false"
      :multiple="false"
      :clear-on-select="true"
      :close-on-select="true"
      :options-limit="300"
      :limit="3"
      :limit-text="limitText"
      :max-height="600"
      :show-no-results="false"
      open-direction="bottom"
      @select="redirect"
      @search-change="updateSearchTerm">
      <span slot="noResult">Oops! No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span>
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
  import { throttle } from 'lodash';

  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

  export default {
    components: {
      Multiselect
    },
    data() {
      return {
        searchTerm: '',
        selectedWork: {},
        works: [],
        isLoading: false
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['worksList']),
    },
    methods: {
      limitText(count) {
        return `and ${count} other works`;
      },
      redirect(work) {
        // redirect to selected page
      },
      updateSearchTerm(term){
        this.searchTerm = term;
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.getWorksAsync();
      },
      getWorksAsync: throttle(function() {
        const term = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        callMyAPI(term)
        .then(results => {
            this.works = results;
            this.isLoading = false;
        })
      }, 200)
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when using `lodash.debounce`. I'm a huge fan of arrow syntax, but I discovered that it was causing `_.throttle()` and `_.debounce()`, etc. to fail.

Obviously my code differs from yours, but I have done the following and it works:

```
export default {
   ...,
   methods: {
     onClick: _.debounce(function() {
       this.$emit('activate', this.item)
     }, 500)
  }
}
```

Even though I'm not using arrow syntax here, `this` still references the component inside the debounced function.

In your code, it'd look like this:

```
export default {
  ...,
  methods: {
    getWorksAsync: throttle(function(term) {
      // the plan is to replace this with an API call
      this.works = this.worksList.filter(work => titleMatches(work, term));
    }, 200)
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @dzwillia.  I think the important difference between your situation and mine is that the `<multiselect>` component is bound to a model `selectedWork` that is _not_ the value we need for the backend API call.  We actually need the user's search string.  But the throttled call doesn't get passed the search string, thus the need for both updating it and watching for those updates then triggering the call.